# Coupling for internal diameter of 1 1/2 abs pipe

Tags: plumbing

I'm looking for a coupling/adapter/reducer that will fit the **inside diameter** of a 1 1/2" abs pipe, in order to extend drain pipe further from the wall and connect to p-trap for vanity sink.

The existing outlet coming out of the wall is partially recessed into the wall, the old 1 1/2 pipe was cut flush with the connector leaving no way reconnect a piece of pipe (without removing vanity and cutting drywall to access). I could try to chisel/Dremel the old pipe away from the connector and hopefully re-use and re-attach a piece of new pipe to the existing connector. I've tried big box stores and plumbing shop to see if they had anything, no luck. I've seen YouTube video with PEX pipe inserts that resolve similar problems but not sure if anything exists that would work with 1 1/2 abs pipe.

appreciate any info and advice please.

Comment: For clarity, please [edit] in a clear, well lit, focused picture of your pipe stub out.

Comment: Also, an _internal_ fitting will catch and hold hair and other goop that gets washed down the drain, leading to quick clogging. That's why pipe fittings are always external - it leaves a nice, smooth internal pipe wall that minimizes the chance of things catching. Your best bet is likely to be cutting a little larger hole in the vanity and wall and putting a standard coupling on the outside of the pipe and gluing in another short horizontal piece to extend it out.

Answer (score 2):

There are tools to solve this **correctly** by drilling out the stub pipe from the connector hub, leaving the hub reusable. So you just glue in a longer piece of normal pipe, in the usual fashion.

Various names, various prices, quite possibly rentable at your local tool rental.

"Socket Saver" and "Hub Saver" are two names.

[image: Socket Saver from ace hardware website]

Far more expensive, might be worth it to a pro plumber with replaceable bits and a longer pilot section to keep it on track better. Dubious unless you can rent one, for a homeowner's needs - but cheaper than hiring a plumber, I guess - **plastic pipe reamer**:
[image: Pipe fitting reamer from Grainger] [image: Plastic pipe reamer from Reed]

Comment: IIUC, you're suggesting using this to completely remove the horizontal stub out from the wall all the way back to the elbow heading down, then gluing in a whole new stub out pipe? I'm no professional plumber, but that seems challenging.

Comment: That is correct. "All the way back to the sanitary tee" (elbow down is S-trap city) isn't far, given that the reason you use these is that someone cut off the pipe without leaving enough to glue a coupling on to what's left of the pipe. If that's not the case you glue on a coupling. Question states "**was cut flush with the connector**" so this is the tool for the job.

Comment: I read "cut flush with the _connector_" as "cut flush with the _wall_". This makes much more sense now.

Comment: I've had some success (destructively) removing PVC pipe from glued fittings using a heat gun (you direct the heat to an extent, and it also appears that the fittings do not soften as fast as the pipe, to an extent) but I have no idea if the same "trick" works with ABS. This is surely the right tool for both types, and the first version I can find for $10-$20 while the fancier ones are under $100, (in these small pipe sizes) so still cheaper than having a plumber show up, much less having them do anything. But I'd **start** by calling the tool rental place.

Comment: thanks everyone for your response and answers. It was cut flush with the connector and not the wall... the connector is recessed into the wall. Appreciate the advice and  recommendations.