# Kitchen sink drain fittings

Tags: drain, kitchen-sink

Hi guys i have a problem got a new sink and drain does not line up so had to cut back the P-trap. The drain coming from the wall is so close i didnt want to cut it. How can i reuse this fitting or should i cut it off and cut some of the wall to gain access? Let me know yiur suggestions [image]

Comment: Yet another place where what you need is a socket saver / hub saver / plastic pipe reamer (or not to have cut that pipe too short for a coupling, but now that ship has sailed...)  As seen here: https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/245650/18078

Answer (score 1):

You could possibly attach a Fernco coupling to what's left of that ABS fitting and then add what you need to attach to the sink. A much better solution would be to cut the rest of the fitting off and save as much of the pipe into the wall as possible. Then start from scratch, opening up a wall a bit if needed.

Comment: I opted to cut it all the way back and redo-it. Much easier than i thought… thanks for the help

Comment: @Jay if you have a solution, please write it up as an answer of your own, then click the check-mark. That way, others will know that this question has been answered suitably. It will save time & effort for those looking to answer and may help others who have run into a similar situation.

Comment: Jay thanks are by upvotes or accepting the answer the check mark that acknowledgment shows other the advice was helpful and or what you ended up doing.