PVC pipe repair: replace or repair
PVC pipe snapped:  Is it possible to remove the segment inside the "T" and keep it in service?
Or is it necessary to replace the T?

Some searching for pvc pipe reamer should get you some answers re: removing the remains of the pipe from the socket.

There is a tool just for this, that grinds/sands the broken stud out saving the coupling.

See: https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/245650/18078 for the tools, but this looks suspiciously like CPVC rather than PVC, and usually the tools are not worth buying if you have access to simply replace an inexpensive fitting. If the tool saves having to open up a wall and cut into a stack, they are well worth it.

it does not matter what tool or method you use by trying to remove it, you will always have chunks falling down the pipe and eventually blocking it

The CPVC "T" was replace and bracketed into the concrete block with Tapcon screws.   In this case it was fast because access was easy and there was enough spare original pipe.  Thanks to everyone who responded: especially with tool examples.
